# Angular weird behavior in http response

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm calling my api that returning a json in the response. I'm calling as below:

```js
getAllLearn() {
    this.learnService.getAllLearn().subscribe(res =>{
        // in result of log is I have res.featured which has only one index (0)
        console.log(res);
        this.myvar = res.featured;
    })
}
```

Then I add this code to the end:

```
this.myvar[1] = res.featured[0];
```

Then in console log I get 2 indexes (0,1). Why does this happen? (I know the built in console.log has some problems but really can not understand this)

Finally my code is:

```js
getAllLearn() {
    this.learnService.getAllLearn().subscribe(res =>{
        // ---- Now it contains two indexes in my res.featured ----- 
        console.log(res);
        this.featured2 = res.featured;
        this.featured2[1] = res.featured[0];
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you parse the JSON? And what is in your Network tab on server response? P.S. It would be useful to see your service's logic

Comment: Don’t console.log to debug code, use a debugger instead.

Comment: @Sergey It has nothing  to do with service. Service is simply sending an http request to server and servery just simply sending a json which the featured index has only one index. When I add the last line of code, this happesn. I think this mostly relates to console.log

Comment: @emix More info please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because javascript copy references, not values. Something like pointers on `C` language.

Example:

```
var a = [];
var b = a;

console.log(a.length); // 0
b.push('something');
console.log(a.length, b.length); // 1, 1
```

The same occurs with your code.

To clone an array on Javascript, you can do:

#### 1. [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var a = [];
var b = a.slice();
```

#### 2. [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (ES6 only)

```
var a = [];
var b = [...a];
```

This option will work only on ES6 compatible browsers (95.25% of users [according to caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=spread)]